# Bootstrap navbar fixed top toggle not showing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap navbar fixed at the top and the toggle doesnt show when I resize the browser. I dont know what i am missing but everything else is working fine. I followed the code on the navbar example site here : [Fixed top navbar example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

```
 <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-header-full navbar-default">

        <div class="header-full-title">
            <img src="~/Content/img/MTC_logo_header.png" class="img-responsive" />
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle=".navbar-collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">VISIT</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">DIRECTORY</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar">CONDOS</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class=" nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">OUR STORY</a></li>

                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">VISIT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">DIRECTORY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">CONDOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">APARTMENTS</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="navStyle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">EVENTS</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropDownMTC pull-right">
                        <li><a href="#">YOGA ROCKS THE PARK</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MONDAY NIGHT MOVIES</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HORSES OF HONOR</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">THURSDAY IN THE PARK</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EVENT SHUTTLE</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">HOLIDAY LIGHTS FESTIVAL</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" class="navStyle">NEWS</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>

            </nav>

          </div>
```

### CSS

```
            .navStyle{

           color:white;
         padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
          margin: 0px;
         text-decoration:none;

        }
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted your CSS code and/or perhaps made a fiddle reproducing the issue.

Comment: its using bootstrap the only custom class is navstyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because of these:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle=".navbar-collapse" .../>
```

Removing these collapse properties should make this work

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle=".navbar-collapse" .../>
```

Comment: that did it. Thanks for the help!